# C# Delete line from .txt extension with a changing filename

Tags: c#, text, overwrite

I am currently trying to make an .exe in c# that I can drag and drop a .txt file onto to remove lines of text that contain the keywords "CM" and/or "Filling". It must be able to overwrite the existing data so there are no new files created. The filename is different every time except for the extension. The data is tab delimited if that has any bearing. I'm aware that there are similar questions to this but I haven't managed to adapt them to suit my needs. Also, I'm very new to this and I've been trying for about a week with no luck.

```
            if (args.Length == 0)
            return; // return if no file was dragged onto exe
        string text = File.ReadAllText("*.txt");
        text = text.Replace("cm", "");
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[0])
            + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
            + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[0])
            + "_unwrapped" + Path.GetExtension(args[0]);
        File.WriteAllText("*.txt", text);

\\attempt 1

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string concrete = "CM";
            string line;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\drocc_000\Desktop\1611AN24T99-041805221704.txt"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\drocc_000\Desktop\1611AN24T99-041805221704NEW.txt"))
                {
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // if (String.Compare(line, yourName) == 0)
                        //    continue;

                        writer.WriteLine(line.Replace(concrete, ""));
                    }
                }
            }
\\attempt 2
```

Thanks for your time.
Regards,
Danny

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and we'll help you fix any issues you have. That means we need a [mcve]

Comment: 1. Read the file into memory, 2. Modify the contents (in memory), 3. Write the (modified) contents from memory back to the file. Any questions?

Comment: Apologies, I have about 5 different attempts with varying degrees of success. I tried StreamWriter method but Visual Studio said I was missing a 'using' statement. Tried a 'ReadAllLines()' approach but I couldn't work out what syntax I was missing. I left all that out so as not to complicate things. I don't know enough to adapt previous answers to similar questions. Trying to learn as quick as I can on evenings, lunch breaks, and weekends alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a console application with the code below and then drag and drop your text file into the .exe file without opening it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0 && File.Exists(args[0]))
        {
            string path = args[0];
            EditFile(new List<string>() { "CM", "Filling" }, path);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void EditFile(List<string> keyWords, string filename)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
            sr.Close();
        }

        int removedLinesCount = 0;
        bool writeline;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                writeline = true;
                foreach (var str in keyWords)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(str))
                    {
                        writeline = false;
                        removedLinesCount++;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (writeline)
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(removedLinesCount + " lines removed from the file " + filename);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(filename, File.ReadAllLines(filename).Where(line => !line.Contains(str)));`

Comment: Can you also count the removed lines with that expression?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the filename from the applications arguments
                string filename = args[0];

                // Read in all lines in the file.
                var linesInFile = File.ReadLines(filename);

                // Filter out the lines we don't need.
                var linesToKeep = linesInFile.Where(line => !line.Contains("CM") && !line.Contains("Filling")).ToArray();

                // Overwrite the file.
                File.WriteAllLines(filename, linesToKeep);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```